# HTML- Xpath Query to Select only node having style attribute and except OL node

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack.
I need to write xpath query expression which will select all nodes having "style" attribute except "ol" i.e. order list node ?
Could anyone please answer this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body/*[not(self::ol)][@style]");
```

Comment: Hi.. Tried this just now.. But it is not giving desired output.

Comment: Hello. just changed a bit and used //*[not(self::ol)][@style] worked for me.

Comment: Glad it helped with little tweak